# How to translate computation in index notation into sequence of SIMD ops in general case?

Tags: numpy, math, tensorflow, linear-algebra, simd

**UPD**: the question in it's original form is poorly formulated because I strongly confuse terminology (SIMD vs vectorized computations) and give too broad example that does not specify exactly what is the problem; **I voted to close it** with "unclear what you're asking", I'll link a better-formulated question above whenever it appears

---

In mathematics, one would usually describe n-dimensional tensor computation using index notation, that would look something like:

```
A[i,j,k] = B[k,j] + C[d[k],i,B[k,j]] + d[k]*f[j] // for 0<i<N, 0<j<M, 0<k<K
```

but if we want to use any SIMD library to efficiently parallelize that computation (and take advantage of linear-algebraic magic), we would have to express it using primitives from `BLAS`, `numpy`, `tensorflow`, `OpenCL`, `...` that is often quite tricky.

Expressions in [Einstein notation][1] like `A_ijk*B_kj` are generally solved via [`np.einsum`][2] (using `tensordot`, `sum` and `transpose`, I guess?). Summation and other element-wise ops are also okay, "smart" indexing is quite tricky, though (especially, if an index appears more then single time in the expression).

I wonder if there any language-agnostic libraries that take an expression in certain form (lets say, form above) and translates it into some `Intermediate Representation` that can be efficiently executed using existing linear-algebra libraries?

There are libraries that attempt to parallelize loop computations (user API usually looks like `#pragma` in C++ or `@numba.jit` in python), but I'm asking about slightly different thing: translate abritary expression in form above into a finite sequence of SIMD commands, like elementwise-ops, matvecs, tensordots and etc.

If there are no language-agnostic solutions yet, I am personally interested in numpy computations :)

Comment: I wounder what is wrong with the question? The answer "no, and that is impossible because X" is an acceptable answer too :) I would be very happy if that kind of library\algorithm existed (and I'm not alone). I have reformulated question in case the question form itself is ugly.

Comment: Can you write a loop in C or some kind of pseudocode that clearly expresses the kind of calculation you want to vectorize?  I'm not sure I understand your `{}` notation.  If it's anything like a matrix multiply, though, yes, transposing one of the inputs is often really useful so that the data you need for consecutive results is stored contiguously in both sources.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for a comment! I agree, I have updated the question, does the notation look less ambiguous now?

Comment: Also, why does `i` not appear in the right hand side?  Is the same data repeated `N` times??

Comment: (my comments were becoming an answer, so I posted them as such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Further questions about the code:**

- I see `B[k,j]` is used an an index and as a value. Is everything integer? If not, which parts are FP, and where does the conversion happen?
- Why does `i` not appear in the right hand side? Is the same data repeated N times?

---

Oh yikes, so you have a gather operation, with indices coming from `d[k]` and `B[k,j]`. Only a few SIMD instruction sets support this (e.g. AVX2).

I mostly manually vectorize stuff in C, with [Intel's x86 intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/), (or auto-vectorization and check the compiler's asm output to make sure it didn't suck), so IDK if there's any kind of platform-independent way to express that operation.

I wouldn't expect that many cross-platform SIMD languages would provide a gather or anything built on top of a gather.  I haven't used numpy though.
I don't expect you'd find a BLAS, LAPACK, or other library function that includes a gather, unless you go looking for implementations of this exact problem.

With an efficient gather (e.g. Intel Skylake or Xeon Phi), it might vectorize ok if you use SIMD in the loop over `j`, so you load a whole vector at once from `B[]`, and from `f[]`, and use it with a vector holding `d[k]` broadcast to every position.  You probably want to store a transposed result matrix, like `A[i][k][j]`, so the final store doesn't have to be a scatter.  You definitely need to avoid looping over `k` in the inner-most loop, since that makes loads from `B[]` non-contiguous, and you have `d[k]` instead of `f[j]` varying inside the inner loop.

---

I haven't done much with **GPGPU**, but they do SIMD differently. Instead of short vectors like CPUs use, they have effectively many scalar processors ganged together. OpenCL or CUDA or whatever other hot new GPGPU tech might handle your gathers much more efficiently.

---

> SIMD commands, like elementwise-ops, matvecs, tensordots and etc.

When I think of "SIMD commands", I think of [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) assembly instructions (or ARM NEON, or whatever), or at least C / C++ intrinsics that compile to single instructions. :P

A matrix-vector product is not a single "instruction".  If you used that terminology, every function that processes a buffer would be "a SIMD instruction".

The last part of your question seems to be asking for a programming-language independent version of numpy, for gluing together high-performance library functions.  Or were you thinking that there might be something that would inter-optimize such operations, so you could write something that would compile to a vectorized loop that did stuff like use each input more than once without having to reload it in separate library calls?

IDK if there's anything like that, other than normal C compiler auto-vectorization of loops over arrays.

Comment: yes, let us assume that all of them are integer; that is not an actual problem, I just wanted to illustrate that the expression includes gathers, multiplications and sums; actually I'm only interested in `gather` part; by `SIMD` I meant all operations that perform "similar operations across large amounts of data" (i.e. element-wise ops, vector ops, gathers, etc.), which is probably a terminology confusion from my side - is it?

Comment: your answer is indeed very detailed and helpful, and it answers the question I formulated (the problem is that in current formulation it asks not what I initially wanted to know :) ) - I don't want to change the question to make your answer obsolete (because your answer is great!), don't you mind if I accept it now and link a new better-formulated question whenever it appears?

Comment: my question was basically "given a complicated gather statement like `result[i, j, k] = A[B[i, j], k, c[i]]` - how one can automatically translate it into a smart-indexing expression (for numpy) or a sequence of transposes, reshapes and 1d-gathers (for tensorflow)", because every time I need to code something like this, I spend some time re-inventing how to reshape\transpose data to get desired result; I usually succeed in the end, but I wish I could just write something like `result[i, j, k]=..` (above)

Comment: @BenUsman: Yeah, there are sort of two parts to this question.  One about that specific expression, and one about a numpy notation for this kind of thing.  Since I don't use python, I wasn't able to say much about the other part.  A new question referencing this sounds like the best plan.  And maybe even edit this question to match the part I did answer, if you think that's worth it for future readers / searchers.